# Simple web server on bash ERROR (failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: bash, shell, server, localhost, webserver

My task was:Create a bash web server that will listen to the port specified in the TCP parameters and process HTTP requests with the GET method. Other HTTP methods do not need to be processed. The server must return to the client static HTML files from the specified root directory or the index.html file. If the index.html file is missing from the server's root directory, the server must return the contents of that root directory. The server should send HTTP responses with codes: 200, 400, 404. Example command to start the server: shell_web_server 8081 ~/web/.

So I wrote such a script in the file shell_web_server :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <port> <root_directory>"
    exit 1
fi

port=$1
root_directory=$2

if [ ! -d "$root_directory" ]; then
    echo "Root directory '$root_directory' does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

index_file="$root_directory/index.html"
if [ ! -f "$index_file" ]; then
    index_file=""
fi

handle_request() {
    request=$1
    response=""

    path=$(echo "$request" | awk '{print $2}')

    if [ "$(echo "$request" | awk '{print $1}')" != "GET" ]; then
        response="HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\nBad Request"
    else
        file_path="$root_directory$path"

        if [ -f "$file_path" ]; then
            response="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n$(cat $file_path)"
        elif [ -d "$file_path" ]; then
            response="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n$(ls -l $file_path)"
        else
            response="HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\nFile Not Found"
        fi
    fi

    echo -e "$response" | nc -q 0 -l -p "$port"
}

echo "Starting web server on port $port"
while true; do
    request=$(nc -l -p "$port")
    handle_request "$request" &
done
```

When I run it, it says : "Starting web server on port 8297", but when I try to navigate in the browser to localhost:8297 I get "(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".
Can you please help what is my mistake and how to fix it.

Comment: If you run `nc` two fimes, you will need two connections, this won't work. You have to run`coproc nc -l -p $port` , then deal with `I/O`  through `$COPROC` ***FDs***. See `help coproc`!

Comment: Alternatively to `nc`, you could use *loadable* `accept` bash command.

Comment: I haven't worked with `nc` yet, but you are using the option `-p`, and the [nc man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) says about this option: _It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option_. What happens if you just do a `nc -l $port`?

Comment: @user1934428 thanks, it works! Sorry for not replying for so long.